# Access nested data api objects in react native

Tags: json, xml, react-native, api, axios

I need to access the data inside the object "priceRange" inside this api data structure 'https://api.chvcfcz6km-enapsysbu1-s1-public.model-t.cc.commerce.ondemand.com/geawebservice/v2/marketplace/products/search' but I haven't found the way to do it, I'm doing an axios call in react native as I show below:

```
            export const RecommendationsView: React.FC = () => {
                const [fetching, setFetching] = React.useState(true)
                const navigation = useNavigation<NavigationProps>()
                const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
                const [items, setItems] = useState<any[]>([])

                const getData = async () => {
                    const res = await axios.get(
                        'https://api.chvcfcz6km-enapsysbu1-s1-public.model-t.cc.commerce.ondemand.com/geawebservice/v2/marketplace/products/search'
                    )
                    console.log(res.data)
                    setItems(res.data.products)
                    setLoading(true)
                    setFetching(false)
                    //este setloading me habia funcionado la idea es reemplazarlo por el setfetching
                }

                React.useEffect(() => {
                    getData()
                }, [])

                return (
                    <View>
                        <View sx={Styles.header} />
                        {items?.map((item, index) => {
                            return (
                                <View key={index}>
                                    <Text>{`${item?.name} + ${item?.priceRange}`}</Text>
                                </View>
                            )
                        })}
                    </View>
                )
            }
```

the call {item?.name} returns me correctly the items name, but if I do something like {item?.priceRange} or any of the data inside priceRange, it only returns [object Object] or undefined.

Comment: Nothing wrong with how you access it, API just returns an empty object for priceRange.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your API return `XML Response` not `JSON Response`, you have to convert it to a json to make it work correctly.

[image]

Comment: do you know how could I do it?

Comment: Please mark it as a correct answer and to solve it you can use this library react-native-xml2js

Comment: API can return both JSON and XML. By default it is returning JSON. Whatever is the format priceRange is empty.